# XML multiple prefixes with same namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces

In XML if we have 2 different namespaces defined like this for example

```
xmlns:a="http://something.com"
xmlns:b="http://something.com"
```

and then 2 different elements, `Element1` and `Element2`, where `Element1` uses the prefix `a` and `Element2` uses the prefix `b`.

Do these 2 elements still consider to be belonging to the same namespace or different namespace? Also, isn't this defeating the whole purpose of having namespaces anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do these 2 elements still consider to be belonging to the same namespace

Yes.

> or different namespace?

No.

> Also, isn't this defeating the whole purpose of having namespaces anyway?

No.